# Delete inner UL and Li elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, detach

I have structured UL/Li like this

```
<ul>
 <li><a>1.1</a></li>
 <li>.....</li>
 <li><a>1.N</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a>2.1</a></li>
         <ul>
           <li><a>3.1</a></li>
           .....
           <li><a>3.N</a></a></li>
         </ul>
    </ul> 
</ul>
```

I want to remove all UL and LI elements and keep all  tags. My goal is get menu as multi row strings.

How I can do it with jQuery?

Comment: What do you want the resulting object to look like?

Comment: need a far better and more detailed explanation... currently impossible to understand what you want. For example, what's a tag in your html? WHat does `multi-row strings` mean

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer.  I try to execute next function
jQuery( init );
 function init() 
{
jQuery('ul li:not(:first):not(:last)').detach();
}

But this functions deletes all! And not keeps data in innner <li> elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you:

Js:

```
var tags = $("ul li").map( function(){
          return $(this).html();
        }).get();      // get all tags in an Array.  I suspect you meant Array by saying `multi row strings`
$("#main ul").remove();

$("#main").append(tags);
```

Fot Html;

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
 <li><a>1.1</a></li>
 <li><a>1.N</a></li>
 <li><ul>
      <li><a>2.1</a></li>
       </li><ul>
           <li><a>3.1</a></li>
           <li><a>3.N</a></a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/S9GXe/2/)

Comment: Hi A. V. Your code returns result 3 times. Your code remove all tags, but returns full list of <a> and adds UL/Li from second and other sub levels.

I modify your code. So it works properly now

var tags = jQuery("ul li").map( function(){
          return jQuery(this).html();
        }).get();      
jQuery("#exp_horizMenu").append(tags);
jQuery("#exp_horizMenu span").remove();
jQuery("#exp_horizMenu ul").remove();

anyway, thank you for idea.

Comment: Anyways, I wasn't clear of your Html code structure and which all tags you need to append.. Just wanted to give you an idea on how to start with... Glad that you made it with your effort... Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your HTML. You can't have `ul` elements inside other `ul` elements, they have to be inside the `li` elements:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>1.1</a></li>
  <li><a>1.2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a>1.N</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>2.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>3.1</a></li>
          <li><a>3.N</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To remove the lists and keep the links, move the links out of them and then remove the lists. For example:

```
$('ul>li>a').appendTo(document.body);
$('ul').remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kRBRC/

Comment: @user2177635: It keeps the `a` elements and removes the `ul` and `li` elements. Check the demo.